# Common code for dependency injection for web api, admin panel and mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Currently, I have below 4 projects in my solution file :

1. API (Web API)
2. Web (MVC)
3. Admin (MVC)
4. Service Layer (C# Library)

The service layer is being used by all the 3 web projects.
The service is injected using Autofac container.

The services are registered in each of the web projects during startup which is causing duplication of the code. Is there a simpler way where I can register all the dependencies in one place so that it can be reused by all the projects?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If the service layer is currently being used and injected into 3 projects, how is there duplication of code? Or have i mis-understood?

Comment: [Composition root reuse](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/) is a bad idea. You are literally defeating the purpose of loose coupling if you put the same coupling code in all 3 applications. It essentially means that you lose the ability to override any component in a specific application. That said, there is no reason why you couldn't use a convention to handle most cases so you don't have so much duplicated code (for example `ISomeService` automatically maps to `SomeService`).

Comment: @wheels73 by duplication I mean I have to register the services (Autofac) in each of the web projects. Eg :   

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>()
                   .As<ICacheManager>()
                   .InstancePerRequest();

            // Task Service
            builder.RegisterType<UserTaskService>()
                   .As<IUserTaskService>()
                   .InstancePerRequest();

Answer (score 0):

Your service layer should be registering instances of interfaces  (programming against an interface).  For example:

```
// Services.DLL
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void DoFoo();
}

internal class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  public void DoFoo()
  {
  }
}
```

Then you can simply use [Aufofac's Scanning For Modules](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#scanning-for-modules):

```
// Services.Dll
public class ServicesRegistrion : Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Register<MyClass>()
      .As<IMyInterface>()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  }
}
```

Then in each project:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager
  .GetReferencedAssemblies()
  .Cast<Assembly>();

foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
{
  builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I will make the changes and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach you can try

- Add a common file like **AutofacBootstrap**, expose a static method which
  excepts Autofac Container, this method  should register all your common
  classes. You can have this file in a separate common project.
- Include that class as a link to other projects. For this
  Right-click the project, select Add > Existing Item, and in the
  dialog drop down the Add button and select Add As Link.

  [image]

  Now you have a common file which have a link to all the projects.
- Next is, in startup of individual project, call the common method by
  passing the container. In addition bootstrap your local dependencies.

I hope this helps.